# Missing Server Side Dependencies MissingWebPart

Tags: web-part, migration, health-analyzer

I have a site that has a "missing server-side dependencies" rule hit, but the webpart that the script is listing doesn't seem to match any errors. They are all legit webparts that run.

- Tried ?contents=1
- Tried powershell to enumerate webparts (all legit)
- Tried `stsadm -o databaserepair`
- Tried to Remove all Webparts that match "ErrorWebPart"
- Tried to Dismount and remount the content database, error comes back

  Output:

  ```
  Id             : d6e70663-9fa7-486f-ad65-46aba9b6688b
  SiteId         : bab515f7-ccee-4816-a122-999dac5358ed
  DirName        : sharepoint/subsite/subsite
  LeafName       : default.aspx
  WebId          : f0cf081b-3d9a-4ae4-b36f-3df8c7580ac5
  ListId         : 
  tp_ZoneID      : Right
  tp_DisplayName : 

  Id             : d6e70663-9fa7-486f-ad65-46aba9b6688b
  SiteId         : bab515f7-ccee-4816-a122-999dac5358ed
  DirName        : sharepoint/subsite/subsite
  LeafName       : default.aspx
  WebId          : f0cf081b-3d9a-4ae4-b36f-3df8c7580ac5
  ListId         : 
  tp_ZoneID      : Right
  tp_DisplayName : 

  Id             : cb0f1822-9dc2-41d4-8aae-11d293891774
  SiteId         : bab515f7-ccee-4816-a122-999dac5358ed
  DirName        : sharepoint/subsite
  LeafName       : default.aspx
  WebId          : afda6158-c9fd-468e-a381-1ba92f8817fa
  ListId         : 
  tp_ZoneID      : Left
  tp_DisplayName :
  ```

The default.aspx has nothing but legit webparts:

- LVWP, XSLT ListView WebPart, PageViewer WebPart , Image Webpart

I don't want any answers that are not supported. No SQL Scripts to remove these features, only supported methods, thanks.

Comment: did you try to use the Codeplex solution find the culprit...http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: how can I do that to find faulty webparts?

Comment: did you open the site in SPM? you can browse each page and find the where that id's exist...i dont think it will tell you if their is any fault...another tool which give you link if you type the id http://featurenamefromid.codeplex.com/

Comment: You mean http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ ? I can't find any features that are faulty.

Comment: it will tell you if feature is faulty rather it will tell you if their is any feature exist with the ID..

Comment: The last place to check would be the site pages or pages and check the versions. I had 55 missing references in one site for the same web part and i could not figure out what on earth could have caused it. It was until i check the number of versions of that page, it showed i was att version number 56. I did reset it to version 1.0 (sure this gave me blank page but priorities priorities..) and bang. All the missing references were gone. Could be worth to check out.

Comment: this is for default.aspx and not on a publishing site.